# Plot Circle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, geometry

I was asked to find different ways to plot a circle in MATLAB,

It seems boring. However I could come up with some ideas (some might be inefficient!),

**Method 1**

```
ezpolar(@(x)1);
```

**Method 2**

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
plot(sin(t),cos(t));
```

**Method 3**

```
[X,Y,~] = cylinder(1,100);
plot(X(1,:),Y(1,:));
```

**Method 4**

```
ezplot('x^2 + y^2 - 1');
```

**Method 5**

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
ro = ones(1,100);
[X,Y] = pol2cart(theta,ro);
plot(X,Y);
```

and it got interesting.

I'm curious if you have other ideas.

Thanks.

**`Edit`**

**Method 11**

```
azimuth = linspace(-pi,pi,100);
r = ones(1,100);
elevation = zeros(1,100);
[X,Y,Z] = sph2cart(azimuth,elevation,r);
patch(X,Y,Z)
%% (not sure how it works! any improvement suggestions?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to go to polar coordinates, then there's also

**Method 6**

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
rho = ones(1,100);
polar(theta, rho)
```

**Method 7**

```
ezpolar('1') % Shortest?
```

You can also take advantage complex number and [how they're handled](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plot-imaginary-and-complex-data.html?refresh=true) by `plot`:

**Method 8**

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
rho = ones(1,100);
z = rho.*exp(1i*theta);
plot(z)
```

The above could be done on one line. It could also be plotted as:

```
plot(real(z),imag(z))
```

**Method 9**

```
plot(0,0,'o','MarkerSize',100)
```

**Method 10**

```
text(0,0,'\circ','FontSize',200)
```

Many [other unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/search/google.htm?q=circle) [characters](http://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=CIRCLE) can be used to produce circles.

You could extend this to generating circles with differential equations, e.g., [circular orbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_orbit) and circular [limit cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle) (Hopf oscillator).

Answer (score 2):

**Method 12**

```
rectangle('Position', [-0.5, -0.5, 1, 1], 'Curvature', [1 1]);
```

Generalized:

```
circle = @(x, y, r) rectangle('Position', [x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r], ...
    'Curvature', [1 1]);

circle(0, 0, 1);
circle(10, 20, 5);
axis equal;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,