# How to generate random positions with distance between them inside the hexagon?

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, polygon

I am trying to create `N` random pairs of points (N = 50) of a given distances, inside a `500` meters hexagon. The distance D created by using `(dmax - dmin).*rand(N,1) + dmin`, with `dmin = 10` and `dmax = 100` in Matlab. I understant that the first I have to generate a set of points `([x1 y1])` that have at least distance `D` from the main hexagon border, then generate the second set of points `([x2 y2])` that have exact distance `D` from the first set. But sometime I got the problem with the second point outside of hexagon, because if the first position on the hexagol border and plus `D`disance, then the second position is outside of hexagon (I mean that I want to generate random pair position inside of hexagol). Could anybody help me in generating this kind of scenario and fix the problem? Thanks.

For example as

```
R               = 500; % hexagol radius
N               = 50;  % number pair positions
d_min           = 10;  % minimum distance          
d_max           = 100; % maximum distance       
D               = (d_max - d_min).*rand(N,1) + d_min; % randomly distance
X               = [0,0]; % hexagol center
j=0;
while j < N 
    j=j+1;
    theta(j)=2*pi*rand(1,1);
    u= rand()+ rand();
    if u < 1
       r(j) = R * u;
    else
       r(j) = R * (2 - u);
    end
% to create the first position
    x1(j)=r(j)*cos(theta(j)) + X(1,1); % first x positions
    y1(j)=r(j)*sin(theta(j)) + X(1,2); % first y positions
end
% to create the second position
x2(j) = x1(j) + D(j); % second x positions
y2(j) = y1(j) + D(j); % second y positions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite like your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415638/how-to-generate-random-positions-with-distance-between-them) and its solution is almost the same, but it needs a little more math. Let’s focus on one pair of points. There still are two steps:

**Step 1:** Find a random point that is inside the hexagon, and has distance `d` from its border.

**Step 2:** Find another point that has distance `d` from first point.

Main problem is **step 1**. We can say that a points that has distance `d` form a hexagon with radius `r`, is actually inside a hexagon with radius `r-d`. Then we just need to find a random point that lays on a hexagon!

**Polar Formula of Hexagons:**

I want to solve this problem in polar space, so I have to formulate hexagons in this space. Remember circle formula in polar space:

[image]

The formula of a hexagon in polar space is pretty much like its circumscribe circle, except that the radius of the hexagon differs at every `t` (angle). Let’s call this changing radius `r2`. So, if we find the function `R2` that returns `r2` for all `t`s then we can write polar formula for hexagon:

[image]

This image demonstrates parameters of the problem:

[image: **Image**]

The key parameter here is `α`. Now we need a function `Alpha` that returns `α` for all `t`s:

[image]

Now we have all points on border of the hexagon in polar space:

```
r = 500;
T = linspace(0, 2*pi, 181);
Alpha = @(t) pi/2-abs(rem(t, pi/3)-(pi/6));
R2 = @(t) r*cos(pi/6)./sin(Alpha(t));
X = R2(T).*cos(T); 
Y = R2(T).*sin(T);

hold on
plot(X, Y, '.b');
plot((r).*cos(T), (r).*sin(T), '.r')
```

[image: **image**]

**Polar Formula of a Regular Polygon:**

Before I go on I’d like to generalize `Alpha` and `R2` functions to cover all [regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon):

```
Alpha = @(t) pi/2-abs(rem(t, 2*pi/(n))-(pi/(n)));
R2 = @(t) r*cos(pi/n)./sin(Alpha(t));
```

Where `n` is the number of edges of the polygon.

[image: **image**]

**Answer:**

Now we can generate pairs of points just like what we did for the circle problem:

```
r = 500; n = 6;
a = 10; b = 50;
N = 100;
D = (b - a).*rand(N,1) + a;

Alpha = @(t) pi/2-abs(rem(t, 2*pi/(n))-(pi/(n)));
R2 = @(t) r*cos(pi/n)./sin(Alpha(t));

T1 = rand(N, 1) * 2 * pi;
RT1 = rand(N, 1) .* (R2(T1)-D);
X1 = RT1.*cos(T1);
Y1 = RT1.*sin(T1);

T2 = rand(N, 1) * 2 * pi;
X2 = X1+D.*cos(T2);
Y2 = Y1+D.*sin(T2);
```

[image]

**Rotating the polygon:**

For rotating the polygon we just need to update the `Alpha` function:

```
t0 = pi/8;
Alpha = @(t) pi/2-abs(rem(t+t0, 2*pi/(n))-(pi/(n)));
```

This is a test for `n=7`, `N=50000` and `t0=pi/10`:

[image: ![**image**]

Comment: I understand your idea, thank you very much. I will post my source code soon, of coure a litte bit different with you. Once again, thank you for your helping.