# Smallest enclosing regular hexagon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mathematical-optimization

Is there any algorithm / method to find the smallest regular hexagon around a set of points (x, y).

And by smallest I mean smallest area.

My current idea was to find the smallest circle enclosing the points, and then create a hexagon from there and check if all the points are inside, but that is starting to sound like a never ending problem.

Comment: You can find some relevant information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828905/polygon-enclosing-a-set-of-points

Comment: Using the circle enclosing may be a start. The solution lives between the circumscribed hexagon (with any rotation) and the inscribed hexagon (with some other rotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Requirements**

First of all, let's define a hexagon as quadruple `[x0, y0, t0, s]`, where `(x0, y0)`, `t0` and `s` are its center, rotation and side-length respectively.
[image]

Next, we need to find whether an arbitrary point is inside the hexagon. The following functions do this:

```
function getHexAlpha(t, hex)
    t = t - hex.t0;
    t = t - 2*pi * floor(t / (2*pi));
    return pi/2 - abs(rem(t, pi/3) - (pi/6));
end

function getHexRadious( P, hex )
    x = P.x - hex.x0;
    y = P.y - hex.y0;
    t = atan2(y, x);
    return hex.s * cos(pi/6) / sin(getHexAlpha(t, hex));
end

function isInHex(P, hex)
    r = getHexRadious(P, hex);
    d = sqrt((P.x - hex.x0)^2 + (P.y - hex.y0)^2);
    return r >= d;
end
```

Long story short, the `getHexRadious` function formulates the hexagon in polar form and returns distance from center of hexagon to its boundary at each angle. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427667/2093077) for more details about `getHexRadious` and `getHexRadious` functions. This is how these work for a set of random points and an arbitrary hexagon:
[image]

**The Algorithm**

I suggest a two-stepped algorithm:

1- Guess an initial hexagon that covers most of points :)
2- Tune `s` to cover all points

**Chapter 1: (2)** *Following Tarantino in Kill Bill Vol.1*

For now, let's assume that our arbitrary hexagon is a good guess. Following functions keep `x0, y0, t0` and tune `s` to cover all points:

```
function getHexSide( P, hex )
    x = P.x - hex.x0;
    y = P.y - hex.y0;
    r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2);
    t = atan2(y, x);
    return r / (cos(pi/6) / sin(getHexAlpha(t, hex)));
end

function findMinSide( P[], hex )
    for all P[i] in P
        S[i] = getHexSide(P, hex);
    end
    return max(S[]);
end
```

The `getHexSide` function is reverse of `getHexRadious`. It returns the minimum required side-length for a hexagon with `x0, y0, t0` to cover point `P`. This is the outcome for previous test case:
[image]

**Chapter 2: (1)**

As a guess, we can find  two points furthest away from each other and fit one of hexagon diameters' on them:

```
function guessHex( P[] )
    D[,] = pairwiseDistance(P[]);
    [i, j] = indexOf(max(max(D[,])));
    [~, j] = max(D(i, :));
    hex.x0 = (P[i].x + P[j].x) / 2;
    hex.y0 = (P[i].y + P[j].y) / 2;
    hex.s = D[i, j]/2;
    hex.t0 = atan2(P.y(i)-hex.y0, P.x(i)-hex.x0);
    return hex;
end
```

[image]
Although this method can find a relatively small polygon, but as a greedy approach, it never guarantees to find the optimum solutions.

**Chapter 3: A Better Guess**

Well, this problem is definitely an optimization problem with its objective being to minimize area of hexagon (or `s` variable). I don't know if it has an analytical solution, and SO is not the right place to discuss it. But any optimization algorithm can be used to provide a better initial guess. I used GA to solve this with `findMinSide` as its cost function. In fact GA generates many guesses about `x0`, `y0`, and `t0` and the best one will be selected. It finds better results but is more time consuming. Still no guarantee to find the optimum!

[image]

**Optimization of Optimization**

When it comes to optimization algorithms, performance is always an issue. Keep in mind that hexagon only needs to enclose the convex-hall of points. If you are dealing with large sets of points, it's better to find the convex-hall and get rid of the rest of the points.

Comment: So my thinking was correct, this is a optimization problem, and there may not be any optimal solution. But now I´m little bit closer, thank you.

So I´m not missing anything, GA is…